# How to read/change/write ISO-8859-1 files for non coders

Tags: excel, csv, iso-8859-1

I am not a developer so please bear with me with some basic questions.

There is a website where you can fill in a client data form on the site and then export it as a ISO-8859-1 coded file. You can also import ISO-8859-1 coded files there.

I on the other hand have client data in excel in CSV format.

What I would like to do is convert my CSV file in to the ISO encoded format so I can upload my client data files on the site without having to manually type in the form.

I have basic understanding of CSV files, but as I said im not a developer. First I thought I could open the ISO file in excel, just change the data in right columns, save and upload the file but it seems some of the data is indeed coded and not readable.

1. Is there some relatively easy way to learn how to do this (meaning for a non-coder putting a few hours of learning behind it)?
2. If yes, roughly where should I start looking, is there some kind of encoding programs I need to download, does Excel offer some kind of funcionality for this?
3. If no, meaning I would basically need to learn to program, where should I look to find a person who can do this? I guess it's very easy for someone who knows what they are doing? Any specific skills the person needs to have or is it basic programming question regardless of languages?

Thankful for any help, Vilho

Comment: A good text editor (Emeditor or something like it) should do what you want.

Comment: These two "encodings" mean different things and are not quite the same. `ISO-8859-1` indicates the files have a specific "character" encoding - otherwise known as the "Latin-1" alphabe - no umlauts or emojis! [A comparison to ISO-8859-1 would be `utf-8` (or Unicode) encoding] `CSV` specifies the separator between logical elements, or groups, in the file. A CSV file could have ISO-8859-1 encoded contents, or utf-8 contents, each element on a row separated by commas. [A comparison to CSV would be TSV or Tab Separated Values]

Comment: Ok cool, thanks, so I have opened an extracted file in Emeditor, understood that each character is suposed to be in a unique positions calculated from first character in the document. I have "the registry design" so I know in which positions the data should go. How do I go ahead to make it easier to adjust? For example create Excel cells where I can type in data and it will get in to the right position as intended?